# ValueError: Covariance matrix does not match expected returns

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

[I am trying to optimize a portfolio for a certain timer period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePd19.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgC6O.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)